# Can't connect to docker container running minecraft server online

Tags: docker, minecraft, portforwarding

So I've been trying to host my own Minecraft server for a while now and I hit a snag.
I have proxmox `(192.168.2.100)` running an ubuntnu server VM `(192.168.2.101)` which has a docker container running my Minecraft server. I can connect to the server locally just fine using the ubuntu's IP address and minecraft port, but when I try to port forward the server, I can't connect to it. I checked to see if my port was exposed or not and it is so I know it's not that.

[This is the container that I'm using](https://hub.docker.com/r/itzg/minecraft-server/)

Comment: How did you check that the port was open? Were you outside of the network and using the router's IP address instead of the local ones you gave here?

Comment: @JordanPaldino I used [a website to check if the port was open](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

Comment: You need to port forward your router rather than only Docker if you want any internet access to your machine. You'll also need a port forward from the host to the VM that's running the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a long time looking at configurations and some help from the proxmox forum, it turns out that my modem doesn't support NAT reflection which means that any attempts to access my server though my public IP on the same network wouldn't work at all. I used my phone's mobile network to test if I could access the server from outside my local network and it worked just fine!